# Mongodb query to get collection only if criteria matches in with specified time range

Tags: mongodb

I have the following collection in Mongdb

```
[
    {
        "customer_id": "test1@gmail.com",
        "created": 1553082454,
        "event_name": "Add to Cart"
    },
    {
        "customer_id": "test2@gmail.com",
        "created": 1553082954,
        "event_name": "Add to Cart"
    },
    {
        "customer_id": "test1@gmail.com",
        "created": 1553089954,
        "event_name": "Add to Cart"
    },
    {
        "customer_id": "test1@gmail.com",
        "created": 1553089984,
        "event_name": "Add to Cart"
    },
    {
        "customer_id": "test1@gmail.com",
        "created": 1553090994,
        "event_name": "Purchased"
    },
    {
        "customer_id": "test2@gmail.com",
        "created": 1553342154,
        "event_name": "Purchased"
    }
]
```

I need the query to get the list of all customers where the time difference between "Purchased" and "Add to Cart" is more than 15 mins with a specified range (eg: in the last 30 days).

```
[
    {
        "customer_id": "test1@gmail.com"
    }
]
```